# POST response taking too long

Tags: post, xmlhttprequest, response, delay

Client side Ajax Javascript code is using `XMLHttpRequest` to send a POST request, but I'm getting like a 0.5 second delay in getting the response and I'm trying to find out why, since I'd like it to be faster, more like 0.2 seconds.  Both endpoints are in the same intranet, the client directly connected via ethernet and the server using 802.11b.

Using Wireshark I sniffed the following TCP transactions:

```
Time(ms)     From          To             Info
------------------------------------------------------------------------
0.0          client        server         [SYN]
11.7         server        client         [SYN,ACK]
11.8         client        server         [ACK]
12.0         client        server         [POST]
12.1         client        server         Continuation
39.0         server        client         ACK
46.0         server        client         ACK
150.0        server        client         TCP segment of reassembled PDU
311.0        client        server         ACK
324.0        server        client         HTTP/1.1 200 OK (text/html)
512.0        client        server         ACK
```

The actual post and response are really short.  Basically the content of the POST request is:

```
cmd=getCurXY&chan=CH_L_JX
```

And the content of the response that I'm sending right now is simply:

```
cmd=noresponse
```

The response is being sent as a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`.

Could this transaction be speeded up in some way?
Why does it need a whole half second?

Comment: Have you tried connecting directly via ethernet? It really seems odd that the TCP stack fragments the packets - MTU misconfigured?

Answer (score 0):

Firstable I highly recommend to you add this gem to your development group gems in your gemfile.

```
group :development, :test do
    gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
end
```

It allows you to track time transactions when you are implementing AJAX requests or any kind of request from a web browser. Also remember that Webrick (Default development server used by Rails) is a quite slow development server, so if you can I recommend to you use Puma as a development server and Unicorn as Production one.

Also, do you really need to use a Rails controller to manage those requests? A very good implementation for these kind of projects is to use a middleware. It is still ruby code but it doesn't load all Rails features making responses to be faster. You can find further information in http://railscasts.com/episodes/319-rails-middleware-walkthrough

Regards.